# How to calculate mean in R only when certain %data is non-missing?

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, conditional-statements, lubridate

I have a text file with Date/Time and few columns. There is also missing data in few columns (Missing data is represented by empty cells). I want to calculate mean of every 10 rows but there is a condition involved. Mean of 10 rows should be calculated only if 5% of 10 rows have non-missing data. If not, then average should not be calculated and the mean of those 10 rows should be marked as NA in the output file.

I know to calculate average using following code but I am not sure how to put the 5% condition. Could anyone please help me.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate) 
df <- read.table('D:/Test/Data.txt', header=TRUE, sep = "\t", check.names = FALSE)
mn <- df %>% separate(`Date/Time`, into = c("Date", 
"Time"), sep = "T")
mnf <- mn %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 10, n()))) %>%
  mutate(
     Date = lubridate::ymd(Date), 
     Time = period_to_seconds(hms(Time))
  ) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.8) NA else 
  mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
  mutate(Time = seconds_to_period(Time))

mnf
```

Comment: 5% of 10 rows is 0.5 rows. So if even 1 row is missing that is 10% missing. So you can use `summarise(across(everything(), mean))` which will use the default `na.rm = FALSE`, and if there are any missing values (which will be at a minimum 10% missing values) the result will be `NA`.

Comment: If you had a non-impossible threshold to meet you could code it as `summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > threshold) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the response. So, if I want to calculate average of 15rows and my threshold is 20%, I should write:  summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 3) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))   Is it? f yes, then when I am doing it, it is giving average for that 15-rows group also which have only 2 records and rest 13 records as missing. However, I want it to calculate mean when among 15-rows group, atleast 3 records in a column should have some values. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I wrote the function using a proportion cut-off, just like you wrote the question. `mean(is.na(.x))` gives the **proportion** of `NA` values. So you would use `summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.2) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))`. (You could swap in `sum` for `mean` to have the threshold be a count of rows, not a proportion.)

Comment: But I also think I misread the direction of your cut-off. `~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.2) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))` will return `NA` if more than 20% are missing. It sounds like you want to reverse the direction, `~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) < 0.8) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))` will return the mean as long as less than 80% are missing.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks it worked successfully. My desired code is: ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.8) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))